# CSS : How to make the sticky footer has the same width as sibling?

Tags: html, css, material-ui

I have a basic sticky footer with CSS below

```
.sticky-footer{
position : fixed;
bottom : 0;
}
```

```
<Box>
   <Paper>
      Testing
   </Paper>
   <Paper>
      <Footer className='sticky-footer' />
   </Paper>
</Box>
```

I can get the footer to stick at the bottom but the width is not following it's sibling even they are in the same section`<Box></Box>`.
[image]

and then I tried to set the `width : 100%` but the size is over
[image]

I tried other width setting like `inherit` but not working.

May I know how can align the width to fit with the sibling ?

Comment: Is there anything wrong with position:sticky to make you use fixed? https://jsfiddle.net/3wf5mxqn/

Comment: Hi @G-Cyrillus, thanks for your answer, I tried again the position:sticky, and it's working fine now, properly there is conflict with my other CSS. Thanks again.